# Joblib giving error when loading my model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, joblib

I am trying to build a project, where I will get the data from the webpage and it will be passed to my ML model, the predictions of which will be shown finally. The model is completed and I have it in the .sav -  named as "litemodel.sav" and below is the code for the same.

Below is the text snippet of the error that I am getting. Since there isn't a description attached to it, it is getting difficult to debug. Anyone encountered a similar issue?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\__COURSE IIT\XYZ\ROAD\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    model = joblib.load('litemodel.sav')
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mitta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 658, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mitta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 577, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mitta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\pickle.py", line 1205, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "C:\Users\mitta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\pickle.py", line 1521, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mitta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\pickle.py", line 1572, in find_class
    __import__(module, level=0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.forest'
```

Below is the code producing the error:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import joblib

app = Flask(__name__)
model = joblib.load('litemodel.sav')
```

[1. joblib is installed in the system (I have checked it - below is the text snippet confirming it)
]

```
PS E:\__COURSE IIT\XYZ\ROAD> pip install joblib
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in c:\users\mitta\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (1.3.2)
```

**UPDATE**

Below is the new error (should I get my python to lower version?)

```
File "E:\__COURSE IIT\BTP\ROAD-ACCIDENTS-PREDICTION-AND-CLASSIFICATION\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    model = joblib.load('litemodel.sav')
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mitta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 658, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mitta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 591, in _unpickle
    raise new_exc
ValueError: You may be trying to read with python 3 a joblib pickle generated with python 2. This feature is not supported by joblib.
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: What's the full error message? Please post it as text, not screenshots

Comment: Hey @ForceBru, thanks for responding. I have updated the post with the text.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `joblib` tries to load your file using the built-in `pickle` module. Apparently the `.sav` file refers to the `sklearn.ensemble.forest` module, so `pickle` tries to load it but fails. Do you have scikit-learn installed on your machine? I do, but `import sklearn.ensemble.forest` raises the same error. I don't think the `forest` module exists. There's [`_forest`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py) (with an underscore), but your `.sav` file asks for `forest` without the underscore for some reason...

Comment: Hey @ForceBru, thanks for the input. It worked, I changed the sklearn.ensemble.forest in the .sav file to sklearn.ensemble._forest (seems sklearn.ensemble.forest was an old version). But am getting a new error now, I have updated it in the post. I tried searching on for it, but nothing is working. Should I get my python to earlier version?

Comment: Well, are you actually trying to read a pickle file generated by Python 2? If so, I guess it'd be reasonable to follow the suggestion in the error message.

Comment: @ForceBru, so I should generate the pickle again with python 3, or it makes sense to get it running with python 2 version. I tried doing running it with python, and it gave different errors, so what do you suggest?

Comment: If you can generate the file with Python 3, then try that because Python 2 is no longer supported. Otherwise post a new question specific to the Python 2 error.